# 2 person 2-factor authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to build a system as follows:

- User 1 is a low permission user. They will be using their phone and at some point will need to do a secure action.
- User 2 is an admin user and will be in the same room as user 1.
- User 2 will generate a temporary code on their own device, and then verbally give the code to user 1.
- User 1 will then enter the code given to them to complete the secure action.

Ideally, neither user 1 nor user 2 will reveal their account usernames to each other. The only thing that will be exchanged is the code.

The backend system I am using to build the basic user authentication is in ASP.NET Core MVC & Asp.net Identity, and this will include an API to validate and generate the codes.

Anyone have any ideas about how to implement the code generation and validation?
Potentially the codes will need to be long enough to identify which admin user requested the code (and thus approved the action), but hopefully not too long to become unwieldy (maybe 6-8 characters?)

Comment: You might want to ask this question on the security stack exchange site. Generally, you don't want to implement new security paradigms. It's hard to get them right. Essentially, what you're looking for is administrative approval. Why not build a system where the user attempts the action which then triggers a backend flow that notifies admins (including the one in the room) that user X wants to do action A. The admin in the room can then send a code (via email or text) to user X so they can complete the process. The code could simply be the admin's OTP.

Comment: Have a look at this library for TOTP - https://github.com/kspearrin/Otp.NET

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, and thanks for fixing my formatting!